# How to return my getWin with more than just true or false

Tags: java

I'm trying to get my program to take multiple different return statements so i can have a win split and lose rather than just win or lose and cant seem to figure out how to do it. My program is made to be able to have either you win and it doubles your bet that you made. If you tie you get your money back. if you lose you lose your bet. Ive gotten win and lose to work previously with using a booelean and returning true or false but needed a way to add in a way to do split.

I've tried multiple methods I've seen online but to no avail any help would be appreciated.

```
//Import Random Number Generator
import java.util.Random;

class BlackJackPlayer{
   //Keep the data secure by using private
   private String hand;
   private int sum;
   private int numAces;
   private static Random gen = new Random();
   private String Win;
   private String Lose;
   private String Split;

   private final int ACE = 1;
   private final int JACK = 11;
   private final int QUEEN = 12;
   private final int KING = 13;

   //constructor
   public BlackJackPlayer(){
      hand = "";
      sum = 0;
      numAces = 0;
   }

   //Getter for hand variable
   public String getHand(){
      return hand;
   }

   public String setHand(){
      hand = " ";
      return hand;
   }

   //Getter for sum variable
   public int getSum(){
      return sum;
   }

   public void hit(){
      //local variable
      int currentCard = gen.nextInt(13) + 1;

      if(currentCard > ACE && currentCard < JACK){
         sum += currentCard;
         hand += currentCard + "   ";
      }
      else if(currentCard == ACE){
         sum += 11;
         numAces++;
         hand += "A  ";
      }

      else if(currentCard == QUEEN){
         sum += 10;
         hand += "Q  ";
      }

      else if(currentCard == QUEEN){
         sum += 10;
         hand += "Q  ";
      }

      else if(currentCard == KING){
         sum += 10;
         hand += "K  ";
      }//Ends Else If

      //Is Ace 1 or 11
      if(sum > 21 && numAces > 0){
         numAces--;
         sum -= 10;
      }

   }//ENDS HIT

   public String getWin(BlackJackPlayer other) {
      if(sum > 21){
         Win = "Win";
      }
      else if(sum < other.getSum()){
         Lose = "Lose";
      }
      else if(sum == other.getSum()){
         Split = "Split";

   }
   return Win;
      }


}//end main



import java.util.Scanner;
class BlackJackGame{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      BlackJackPlayer you = new BlackJackPlayer();
      BlackJackPlayer enemy = new BlackJackPlayer();
      int chips = 100;
      int bet;
      int winnings;
      int multiply = 2;
      String qORc;
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      String choice;
      do{
      you.setHand();
      enemy.setHand();
      you.hit();
      enemy.hit();
      enemy.hit();
         System.out.println("Chips: " + chips);
         System.out.println("How much do you want to bet");
         bet = in.nextInt();
         chips -= bet;
         System.out.println("You bet: " + bet + ", You now have " + chips + " chips");
      do{
         System.out.println("Your Cards:  " + you.getHand());         
         System.out.println("(H)it or (S)tand");
         choice = in.next();
         if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("h")){
            you.hit();
         }
      }while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("h"));

      while(enemy.getSum() < 16){
         enemy.hit();
      }
      System.out.println(you.getWin());
       if(you.getWin()){
         System.out.println("You Win");
         System.out.println(enemy.getHand());
         winnings = bet * multiply;
         chips += winnings;
         System.out.println("You now have: " + chips + " chips!");
      }
      else{
         System.out.println("You Lose");
         System.out.println(enemy.getHand());
         System.out.println("You now have: " + chips + " chips.");
      }
               System.out.println("(C)ontinue or (Q)uit");
         qORc = in.next();
      }while(chips > 0 && qORc.equalsIgnoreCase("c"));

   }//end main

}//end class
```

I expect to be able to get different return statements that way I can actually set a win aspect a lose aspect but also a split aspect if both players tie.

Comment: it’s a lot a code to read, maybe focus on the exact problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have three results to return which are: WIN, LOSE and TIE right?

In that case you have to use three different variables like,

```
public String Win = "Win",Lose = "Lose",Split = "Split";
```

and use other variable to store result like `result` and return this result in `getWin()`. See below code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
class BlackJackPlayer{
   //Keep the data secure by using private
   private String hand;
   private int sum;
   private int numAces;
   private static Random gen = new Random();
   public String Win = "Win",Lose = "Lose",Split = "Split";
   private String result = "";
   private final int ACE = 1;
   private final int JACK = 11;
   private final int QUEEN = 12;
   private final int KING = 13;

   //constructor
   public BlackJackPlayer(){
      hand = "";
      sum = 0;
      numAces = 0;
   }

   //Getter for hand variable
   public String getHand(){
      return hand;
   }

   public String setHand(){
      hand = " ";
      return hand;
   }

   //Getter for sum variable
   public int getSum(){
      return sum;
   }

   public void hit(){
      //local variable
      int currentCard = gen.nextInt(13) + 1;

      if(currentCard > ACE && currentCard < JACK){
         sum += currentCard;
         hand += currentCard + "   ";
      }
      else if(currentCard == ACE){
         sum += 11;
         numAces++;
         hand += "A  ";
      }

      else if(currentCard == QUEEN){
         sum += 10;
         hand += "Q  ";
      }

      else if(currentCard == QUEEN){
         sum += 10;
         hand += "Q  ";
      }

      else if(currentCard == KING){
         sum += 10;
         hand += "K  ";
      }//Ends Else If

      //Is Ace 1 or 11
      if(sum > 21 && numAces > 0){
         numAces--;
         sum -= 10;
      }

    }//ENDS HIT

   public String getWin(BlackJackPlayer other) {
      if(sum > 21){
         result = Win;
      }
      else if(sum < other.getSum()){
          result = Lose;
      }
      else if(sum == other.getSum()){
          result = Split;
      }
   return result;
  }
}//end main

class BlackJackGame{
    public static void main(String args[]){
       BlackJackPlayer you = new BlackJackPlayer();
       BlackJackPlayer enemy = new BlackJackPlayer();
       int chips = 100,bet,winnings,multiply = 2;
       String qORc;
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

       String choice;
       do{
          you.setHand();
          enemy.setHand();
          you.hit();
          enemy.hit();
          enemy.hit();
          System.out.println("Chips: " + chips);
          System.out.println("How much do you want to bet");
          bet = in.nextInt();
          chips -= bet;
          System.out.println("You bet: " + bet + ", You now have " + chips + " chips");
          do{
             System.out.println("Your Cards:  " + you.getHand());         
             System.out.println("(H)it or (S)tand");
             choice = in.next();
             if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("h")){
                 you.hit();
             }
          }while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("h"));

          while(enemy.getSum() < 16){
             enemy.hit();
          }
          String result = you.getWin(enemy);
          System.out.println(result);
          if(result == you.Win){
              System.out.println("You Win");
              System.out.println(enemy.getHand());
              winnings = bet * multiply;
              chips += winnings;
              System.out.println("You now have: " + chips + " chips!");
          }
          else if (result == you.Lose){
              System.out.println("You Lose");
              System.out.println(enemy.getHand());
              System.out.println("You now have: " + chips + " chips.");
          }else{
              System.out.println("You Split");
          }
          System.out.println("(C)ontinue or (Q)uit");
         qORc = in.next();
     }while(chips > 0 && qORc.equalsIgnoreCase("c"));

   }//end main

}
```